# CircleCI launch emulator step fails for Espresso Tests with Could not open GL library libGLESv2.so

Tags: continuous-integration, android-espresso, devops, continuous-deployment, circleci

So I have these espresso tests for android, which I have built on CircleCI, but the launch emulator step completes with the following error:

emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'swiftshader_indirect' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
EglOsGlLibrary: Could not open GL library libGLESv2.so [libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
EglOsEglDispatcher: Could not open EGL library libEGL.so [libEGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
Received 'segmentation fault' signal

I have already tried changing the versions for android in the sdk manager command. Tried different versions of docker image for android. All the same. Following is the snippet of config.yml file for CircleCI

```
 - run:
      name: Setup emulator
      command: sdkmanager "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a" && echo "no" | avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a"
  - run:
      name: Launch emulator
      command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib && emulator64-arm -avd test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-window -accel auto -verbose
      background: true
  - run:
      name: Wait emulator
      command: |
        # wait for it to have booted
        circle-android wait-for-boot
        # unlock the emulator screen
        sleep 30
        adb shell input keyevent 82
```